# How do split url(s) using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have some url(s) like this:

```
foo.net
abcd.com
http://www.abc.com/video/ygrefhcbaukly
http://xyz.com/video/lwriey/ew4def

parse_url((url), 'HOST')
```

I tried the above hive UDF,
I'm getting the o/p like this:

```
/N
/N
www.abc.com
xyz.com
```

I want to display the first 2 url(s) also. How do write a hive script for the below o/p?

```
foo.net
abcd.com
abc.com
xyz.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of options you can try

a) You can use a case statement .

case when parse_url((url), 'HOST') is null then url
else parse_url((url), 'HOST') end as parsed_url

In order to replace www you can use a regex or replace function.

b) You can write your own UDF with all the features you need.